# Using Boostrap 4 with Angular 4 while none of the Bootstrap Components (like label and header) are working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular

Good Morning Developers.

I am working on an Angular 4 App as a project for my university classes. I tried to use Bootstrap 4 with it and while the CSS classes are working thanks to a correctly imported CSS file, anything that requires jquery does not seem to work.

I have tried to use this bootstrap label in my HTML files.

```
<h3>Example heading <span class="label label-default">New</span></h3>
```

However, it just appears as a regular label switched a little to the side thanks to the CSS file instead of the popup like the behaviour of the bootstrap label as shown here:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#labels

To install bootstrap I have used the npm commands to install jquery, popper, and bootstrap. I have also linked the scripts in the angular-cli.json file as shown in the picture. Jquery, Bootstrap, and Popper are installed in the newest versions.[relevant part of my angular-cli.json file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5GkY.jpg)

I tried using the min versions of the script files, that did not help.
I can not find the reason on my own, please share your insights.

Comment: bootstrap 4 has changed. see https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/ In your case "label" is "badge"

Answer (score 0):

Did you import the installed bootstrap, popper and jquery in angular-cli.json file?

Kindly import those in following order:

1. jquery
2. popper
3. Bootstrap